# Retry request if error with node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, interceptor

I have an application with node and my app is autenticated (as client) with JWT on an API.

How can I refresh my token when I have an 401 error ?

My project use not Express

my service :

```
const request = require('request');

let config = require('../../configuration');

module.exports = {
    get_movies: function () {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            request({
                method: 'GET',
                uri   : 'http://myapi/v1/movies',
                auth  : {
                    'bearer': config.token
                },
                json  : true
            }, function (error, response, body) {
                if (!error && response.statusCode === 200) {
                    resolve(body);
                } else {
                    reject(response);
                }
            })
        });
    },
    ...
    refreshToken: function () {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            request({
                method: 'GET',
                uri   : 'http://myapi/v1/token-refresh',
                auth  : {
                    'bearer': config.token
                },
                json  : true
            }, function (error, response, body) {
                if (!error && response.statusCode === 200) {
                    resolve(body);
                } else {
                    reject(response);
                }
            })
        });
};
```

I would like to know if it's possible to intercept my (error 401) request on my get_movies function for example, call my refresh token function and after retry my previous function (get_movies) ?

Answer (score 1):

I have been using [got](https://github.com/sindresorhus/got) for this and have been really happy with it.

You can use the `afterResponse` hook to detect error, check that it is 401 and then refresh token and resubmit original request.

From the documentation:

```
const got = require('got');

const instance = got.extend({
    hooks: {
        afterResponse: [
            (response, retryWithMergedOptions) => {
                if (response.statusCode === 401) { // Unauthorized
                    const updatedOptions = {
                        headers: {
                            token: getNewToken() // Refresh the access token
                        }
                    };

                    // Save for further requests
                    instance.defaults.options = got.mergeOptions(instance.defaults.options, updatedOptions);

                    // Make a new retry
                    return retryWithMergedOptions(updatedOptions);
                }

                // No changes otherwise
                return response;
            }
        ],
        beforeRetry: [
            (options, error, retryCount) => {
                // This will be called on `retryWithMergedOptions(...)`
            }
        ]
    },
    mutableDefaults: true
});
```

It's working great for me so far :-)

Comment: The code has been updated to `instance.defaults.options.merge(updatedOptions)`

Answer (score 0):

A simple way would be to put an error handler after your `get_movies` promise to handle the case and retry. Along the lines of:

```
get_retry: function () {
    return get_movies().catch((rejection) => {
        if (rejection.statusCode === 401)
            return refreshToken().then((x) => get_retry())
    })
}
```

Beware of the possibility of an infinite loop if your `refreshToken()` has a possibility to not fix the `HTTP 401`.